# Haskell literals in type inference

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghci, type-systems

Let's say I have a function `($10)`.

Now, since 10 is of type `Num a => a`, `($10)` is surely of type `Num a => (a -> b) -> b`, and GHCi confirms this.

But when I say `let f = ($10)`, GHC infers f's type to be `(Integer -> b) -> b`, as if the `let`-assignment deduced some 'extra' information from the use of the literal.

Does this mean GHC's type inference coerces a concrete type for literals?

But if so, why does `:t ($10)` return `Num a => (a -> b) -> b` ?

```
f :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
f = ($10)
```

typechecks, and `f (+0.1)` yields a correct result, while

```
g = ($10)
```

called with `g (+0.1)` fails, expecting an `Integer`.

Comment: Sounds like the monomorphism restriction. Try using `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` in ghci. Btw - you can type `:set -XNoMonom` and then hit TAB to complete it.

Comment: Monomorphism + GCCi defaulting rules.

Comment: That was it! Monomorphism restriction is turned off by default in newer GHC versions, as it happens I was playing around with 7.0.4

Comment: @CsongorKiss: The monomorphism restriction is turned off by default in newer *GHCis*.  It's still on by default in source files.